# Footer fixed bottom with header and Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.1, with the template "Jumbotron".

Here, my page :

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="root" class="container">
    <div id="main" class="row">
        <section id="content">
            <!-- content -->
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <!-- content -->
    </footer>
</div>
```

On the browser, the header (the div with role "navigation" + div with class "jumbotron") has  a 290px size.

When I'm trying to push the footer at the bottom with all what I found, I have always the same problem. The "root" and "main" div will always be longer than the screen display because of the header, I guess.
A lot of internet's solutions don't include a header... :(

I don't want to fix the footer with a "position:fixed", I realy want to push it at the bottom with CSS only.

To be more specific, my footer has to stay at the bottom of the page with or without content. If the content is sorter than the screen, the footer will be at the bottom of the screen. If the content is longer than the screen, the footer will be at the end of the page.

**EDIT: I don't want to do it WITH Bootstrap. I just want some CSS to do it without Bootstrap if Bootstrap can't do it !**

I hope it's clear enough.

If someone has an idea, it'll make my day!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us some css, and any other code if you have?

Comment: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HFkVO26ljV) This example has a fixed bottom navbar, but I don't really know what you're asking in this situation...

Comment: @NatureShade: for this case, I have no more stuff than Bootstrap.

Comment: @TimLevwis: It can be that, but the footer is fixed on the page. I just want it a the bottom everytime, with or without content in the page.

Comment: @Massprotect See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Massprotect I have updated my answer and i think it answers your problem.

Comment: @NatureShade Unfortunaly, it's not working... The content overlaps the footer :/

Comment: @Massprotect that is what the body margin is for. Just adjust it to fit your footer

Comment: I use jQuery http://blog.mojotech.com/responsive-dynamic-height-sticky-footers/

Answer (score 2):

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/HFkVO26ljV)

Did you try this?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="root" class="container">
  <div id="main" class="row">
    <section id="content">
      <!-- content -->
    </section>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Also if this isn't what you're looking for, edit your question and try to be more detailed.

**EDIT**

OP is looking for the `navbar-static-bottom`, which renders the footer at the very bottom of the page **REGARDLESS* of page content/height. The only issue is, this class has not yet been added to bootstrap.** It's in the list of commits, but has yet to be reliably implemented.

[Commit Log for Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5552)

See this document on the status of `navbar-static-bottom` class. As of right now, there is not reliable way to do this in Bootstrap.

Comment: "just use the default navbar if you're doing that."  This isn't a needed fix. It's people incorrectly using bootstrap framework. Your solution works.

Comment: My solution only works if the content doesn't scroll past the page... As soon as it does, the `fixed-bottom` navbar **OVERLAPS** the content at the bottom of the page. It is literally fixed to the bottom of your screen, not the bottom of the page.

Comment: @TimLewis Oh right... No solution with boostrap directly... Thanks, good to know ! 
Is there a way to do it with custom CSS ?

Comment: Not that I've been able to figure out... I tried to do this exact thing with a project of mine a month or so back, failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you can style your footer with the class of

```
   navbar-fixed-bottom
```

A default footer might look something like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That still says `navbar-static-top` and there is no `navbar-static-bottom`.. I think you mean `navbar-fixed-bottom`

Comment: So it does. Now it says bottom.

Comment: The footer will be fixed at the bottom. I just want the footer to be "push" on the end of the page. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into these examples?

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

or

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

It's been working like a charm for years.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

So you want to keep the footer at the bottom of the page with css, you could just do:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Massprotect have a look at this: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: This is unnecessary in bootstrap.

Comment: @JoeSwindell well, according to Tim Lewis answer the `navbar-static-bottom` is not yet implemented, and this could be the only proper way.

Comment: Because it isn't needed.

Comment: But it really is. You try getting that navbar to stick to the bottom if the content scrolls past the end of the page. When you do, post your working answer instead of just adding comments to ours.